# Как сделать сдвиг массива вправо для вставки нового элемента в начало на python?

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, list, python-2.x

Например.

До смещения `[1,1,0,0,0]`.
После первого смещения вправо `[0,1,1,0,0]`.
После второго `[0,0,1,1,0]`.
И так до первой единички сконца `[0,0,0,1,1]`.

Не циклический сдвиг.
Фактически, в начало массива всегда должен добавляться ноль и при этом содержимое сдвигается вправо. Не удается сообразить. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке есть реализация  [FIFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) [очереди](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), которая позволяет решать вашу задачу вытеснением последнего элемента.

```
from collections import deque

l = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

d = deque(l, len(l))  # второй параметр - ограничение размера очереди

while not d[-1]:      # пока последний элемент очереди - ноль
    d.appendleft(0)   # вставка элемента слева

print(d)  # deque([0, 0, 0, 1, 1], maxlen=5)
print(list(d))  # [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Вариант с очередью и `appendleft` хороший :)

Comment: @gil9red, применение очереди тут само напрашивается при такой формулировке вопроса

Answer (score 6):

Вставить в начало списка значение `0`, удалить последний элемент:

```
def shift_right(items: list):
    items.insert(0, 0)
    items.pop()
```

Проверка:

```
items = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
print(items)  # [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

shift_right(items)
print(items)  # [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

shift_right(items)
print(items)  # [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

shift_right(items)
print(items)  # [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```